# How can I monitor and get http traffic in an android application?

Tags: android, browser

I am wondering is there a way to intercept/monitor http traffic in android. One way which I could think of is to install custom module in android's browser source code such that all traffic goes through it.

Please steer me to the pertinent choice. Else how can we implement custom module, any guidelines?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121732/monitor-network-activity-in-android-phones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the browsers PID, you can use [getUidRxBytes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidRxBytes%28int%29) to get [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)