# Android: How to list all online apps with IPs and Ports

Tags: android, android-internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor network activity in Android Phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121732/monitor-network-activity-in-android-phones)

It is possible in Android to generate a list of all apps, which are  in this moment online,  with  IPs and Ports they are using? Thank you for help

Comment: Only with root privilege.  See this answer for more details:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121732/monitor-network-activity-in-android-phones

Comment: ok, thanks it was helpful, but how can I get this in my app? I would like to do this in my app