# Integrate Nmap and ettercap into an android app

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate Nmap and ettercap, which are unix applications, into an android app.

The problem is I don't even know how to start to do this.

If someone can tell me how can I integrate those 2 apps into my app or how can I integrate an unix app in general into my android and how should I continue from there, I would really appreciate the help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you would have to compile both applications for androids arm processor (and hope that the hardware is supported).

As far as I know, there are at least implementations of tcpdump for android but paket capturing and other kinds of low level network access is something that might require root priviliges on your device.

Maybe you should also have a look at android developer forums - as there seem to be people who successfully compiled these applications for android:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=887412

Comment: I am aware that I need the device to be rooted. SO basically I need to pre install the apps on the android device then I call them using commands sent to the android's terminal ?

Comment: Yes, given that you compiled them for the arm processor thats how it could work, but it is not necessearily the best way. You could also use libpcap for accessing low level network data if that is what you are aiming at. Maybe have a look at this thread also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121732/monitor-network-activity-in-android-phones

Comment: Actually this is my dissertation project for uni, and I aim to create a pentesting tool which integrate some utils used on Backtrack or KAli linux.

Comment: Sounds interesting, good luck! There is already a unstable backtrack / kali implementation for android but you probably already know about it: http://www.kali.org/how-to/kali-linux-android-linux-deploy/

Comment: Yeah I know but it's quite different than what I want to do I aim to do smth more like dsploit