# Access other App's traffic information inside Android app

Tags: android, android-activity

is it possible to read the traffic stats inside my own monitoring and testing app?
I need to send these information to a server to analyse the data of some probands.

Comment: this will require root access

Comment: See this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5143175/3884250)