# How do Android apps which monitor all network activity work?

Tags: android, networking

I need to monitor all network activity on the device as part of my application rather than for debugging purposes.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121732/monitor-network-activity-in-android-phones) talks about using TCP dump, but some answers suggest this requires root. None of the answers really explain how you would do it within an app.

I know it is somehow possible to access all network traffic from within an app, because apps like [Network Connections](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor&utma=xd) can display all IP addresses that are being accessed, and also which apps are accessing them.

Does anyone know which APIs, permissions, etc. I would need to use in order to get this kind of data in my app?

Comment: If it's for debugging it depends what you're using to transport the data. HttpUrlConnection, HttpClient, OkHttp. You can usually log all data going through these pretty easily.

Comment: To clarify, I want to monitor all network activity on the device, not just from my application, and I want it to be exposed to the end user, not just for debugging.  I think the edit another user made caused that to be less clear (though it was overall helpful!)

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking, in the package android.net there's this class:

```
/**
 * Collection of historical network statistics, recorded into equally-sized
 * "buckets" in time. Internally it stores data in {@code long} series for more
 * efficient persistence.
 * <p>
 * Each bucket is defined by a {@link #bucketStart} timestamp, and lasts for
 * {@link #bucketDuration}. Internally assumes that {@link #bucketStart} is
 * sorted at all times.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public class NetworkStatsHistory implements Parcelable {
```

Comment: @user3174484 did you find any way? I am also trying to achieve the same as you are.